# Более длинная история команд

Tags: vim

Как увеличить глубину истории *Vim*?  Имеется в виду история
команд, набираемых через `:`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Справка `:help 'history'`:

```
            *'history'* *'hi'*
'history' 'hi'    number  (Vim default: 50, Vi default: 0,
             set to 200 in |defaults.vim|)
      global
      {not in Vi}
  A history of ":" commands, and a history of previous search patterns
  is remembered.  This option decides how many entries may be stored in
  each of these histories (see |cmdline-editing|).
  The maximum value is 10000.
  NOTE: This option is set to the Vi default value when 'compatible' is
  set and to the Vim default value when 'compatible' is reset.
```

Так что в `~/.vimrc` надо проставить:

```
set history=10000
```